# Got swapped or Got exchanged

Tags: word-usage

At an airport two people accidentally swapped their bags.

> Looks like our bags (accidentally) got swapped.

> Looks like our bags (accidentally) got exchanged.

I think the second one sounds more intentional than unintentional. So does the second sentence work? Is it likely to be used?

Comment: I don't see an inherent implication of intent in either; both can be used for both the accidental and intentional cases. I would tend to call the distinction between the two sentences as one of formality - "exchanged" sounds more formal than "swapped". I don't see that either one is _inherently_ more common than the other; the deciding factor would tend to be the formality of the situation and the comfort level with the language of the speaker.

Comment: So @Jeff Zeitlin is the second one likely to be used?

Comment: Cause when I looked up "got exchanged" in this context, I couldn't pull up anything. So is it wrong? Won't it be used?

Answer (score 1):

They're both perfectly acceptable and mean the same thing in the context you give!

You're also interpreting the connotation color correctly; "exchanged" is less commonly used when there is not active intent.  But it would be completely and immediately understood and sounds natural.